# Javascript - pulling a random string from an array and getting undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, math

I've written a simple script to call a random string from an array, but for some reason it displays 'undefined' every now and then.  I've called the first and last of the array (0 and 42) from the console and they pull the correct item.  I'm using the Chrome browser.

```
document.getElementById("pick").addEventListener("click", function({
  document.getElementById("restaurant").innerHTML = 
    restaurants[Math.floor(Math.random() * restaurants.length - 1)];
});
```

Functional example can be found at:
[LunchBOX](http://lunchbox.redpointaudio.com)

Comment: Can we see the array you're getting the strings from? More code will help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because the order of math operations is incorrect.

For example, `Math.random()` returns `0.01`, then its multiplied by `restaurants.length`, what may be 10. then you have 0.1, then it is subtracted by 1 and is then -0.9. After that it is rounded down and becomes -1. `restaurants[-1]` is `undefined`.

Make it:

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * (restaurants.length - 1))]
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct sentence is:

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * restaurants.length)
```

The random() method returns a random number from 0 (inclusive) up to but not including 1 (exclusive). The index will never be equal to restaurants.length.